# PowerBuilder Azure connection string with SNC

Tags: azure, powerbuilder

our Powerbuilder 11.5 applications are client-server using the SNC driver (SQL Native Driver) to connect to SQL Server databases.

We are thinking of using Azure.

2 questions:

- Can PB 11.5 connect to Azure database using the SNC driver?
- The current DBParms are: `TrimSpaces=1,RecheckRows=1,Identity='SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Will they be
  valid in the Azure environment? Can you post a working SNC or OLEDB connection string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example program can be found at the Topwiz Programming website [here](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_sqlazure.html).

There also is an article from TechWave 2011 [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jimoneil/2011/09/26/techwave-2011-powerbuilder-and-the-cloud/).

Comment: Thank you @Matt Balent! Just for the record, the TopWiz example works if you remove the  ".database.windows.net,1433;" from the dbparm string.